# How to pass a file using GetOpt

Tags: perl, command-line, getopt

I have a program where I need to pass a filename (and location) to the program. How can I do this? I have read the GetOpt doc so please don't point me there. My command line is as follows:

```
perl myprogram.pl -input C:\inputfilelocation -output C:\outputfilelocation
```

My GetOptions look like this:

> GetOptions('input=s' => \$input,'output=s' => \$output);

Basically I need to figure out how to access that file in a while loop that I have which iterates over the lines in the file and puts each into $_

```
while ($input) {
```

...doesn't work.  Note that before my file worked fine with:

```
open my $error_fh, '<', 'error_log';
while (<$error_fh>) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me. Your `GetOptions` seems correct. Open file and read from the filehandle, and don't forget to check for errors:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($input, $output);
GetOptions('input=s' => \$input,'output=s' => \$output) or die;

open my $fh, '<', $input or die;

while ( <$fh> ) { 
    ## Process file.
}
```

Comment: Mine dies at: open my $fh, '<', $input or die;  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1488984 Why does it die? Include the error in the die message: `...or die $!`.

Comment: @TLP: It is saying "readline() on closed filehandle $fh at: while (<$fh>) {

Comment: I forgot to mention that the while statement is inside a subroutine if that matters.

Comment: @user1488984 That means either you never opened your file handle, or the open failed. If you had `or die` on your open statement, that means either your file handle is out of scope, or you misspelled the variable name. It's hard to guess without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to assume that you're being passed filehandles, rather than file names. You need to open the files and assign filehandles to them.

```
# This doesn't work as $input contains a file name
GetOptions('input=s' => \$input,'output=s' => \$output);

# This doesn't work for two reasons:
# 1/ $input is a file name, not a filehandle
# 2/ You've omitted the file input operator
while ($input) {
  ...
}
```

You want something more like this:

```
# Get the file names
GetOptions('input=s' => \$input,'output=s' => \$output);

# Open filehandles
open my $in_fh, '<', $input or die "Can't open $input: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $output or die "Can't open $output: $!";

# Read the input file using a) the input filehandle and b) the file input operator
while (<$in_fh>) {
  ...
}
```

I also think there might be another problem here. I'm no expert on Windows, but I think that your file names might be misinterpreted. Try either reversing the slashes in your command line:

```
perl myprogram.pl -input C:/inputfilelocation -output C:/outputfilelocation
```

or doubling the backslashes:

```
perl myprogram.pl -input C:\\inputfilelocation -output C:\\outputfilelocation
```

or perhaps quoting the arguments:

```
perl myprogram.pl -input "C:\inputfilelocation" -output "C:\outputfilelocation"
```